# MySQL find intersection of overlaps

Tags: mysql

i have a database table containing events:

```
CREATE TABLE events
event VARCHAR(32)
,down_time TIMESTAMP
,up_time TIMESTAMP
,id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
,INDEX(event(16))
);

INSERT INTO events(event, down_time, up_time) VALUES
('e1', '2015-01-01 00:00:04', '2015-01-01 00:00:08'),
('e2', '2015-01-01 00:00:05', '2015-01-01 00:00:06'),
('e3', '2015-01-01 00:00:02', '2015-01-01 00:00:09'),
('e4', '2015-01-01 00:00:01', '2015-01-01 00:00:07'),
('e5', '2015-01-01 00:00:03', '2015-01-01 00:00:10');

SELECT * FROM events;

+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| event | down_time           | up_time             | id |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| e1    | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |  1 |
| e2    | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 |  2 |
| e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  3 |
| e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 |  4 |
| e5    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:10 |  5 |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
    |   |   |   |-------e1------|   |   |
    |   |   |   |   |-e2|   |   |   |   |
    |   |--------------e3-----------|   |
    |----------e4-----------|   |   |   |
    |   |   |-------------e5------------|
```

I would like to identify if all events overlap at any one time. 
So in the above they all intersect here (e2):

```
Overlap |overlap_down_time   | overlap_up_time     | overlap_duration
1       |2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01
```

i can find the overlaps between pairs of events using this query but not sure how to include all events ..many thanks in advance !

```
SELECT
  e1.event AS event1_name,
  e1.down_time AS event1_down_time,
  e1.up_time AS event1_up_time,
  TIMEDIFF(e1.up_time, e1.down_time) AS event1_duration,

  e2.event AS event2_name,
  e2.down_time AS event2_down_time,
  e2.up_time AS event2_up_time,
  TIMEDIFF(e2.up_time, e2.down_time) AS event1_duration,

  GREATEST(e1.down_time,e2.down_time) AS overlap_down_time, 
  LEAST(e1.up_time,e2.up_time) AS overlap_up_time,
  TIMEDIFF( LEAST(e1.up_time,e2.up_time),
  GREATEST(e1.down_time,e2.down_time) ) AS overlap_duration

 FROM events e1

INNER JOIN events e2 ON e1.id < e2.id
WHERE
 ( e2.down_time <= e1.up_time ) 
AND
 ( e2.up_time >= e1.down_time );
```

The solutions proposed below do not appear to cover case where an event occurs twice within the overall timeframe ..as happens for e2 below:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
|   |   |   |-------e1------|   |   |
|   |   |---e2--|   |-------e2------|   
|   |-------------e3------------|   |
|----------e4-----------|   |   |   |

INSERT INTO events(event, down_time, up_time) VALUES
    ('e1', '2015-01-01 00:00:04', '2015-01-01 00:00:08'),
    ('e2', '2015-01-01 00:00:03', '2015-01-01 00:00:05'),
    ('e2', '2015-01-01 00:00:06', '2015-01-01 00:00:10'),
    ('e3', '2015-01-01 00:00:02', '2015-01-01 00:00:09'),
    ('e4', '2015-01-01 00:00:01', '2015-01-01 00:00:07');
```

i have been able to identify the intersect by using a two stage query:

```
CREATE VIEW overlap1 AS
SELECT
CONCAT(a.event,'-', b.event) overlaps,
GREATEST(a.down_time,b.down_time) AS downtime, 
LEAST(a.up_time,b.up_time) AS uptime,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( LEAST(a.up_time,b.up_time),
    GREATEST(a.down_time,b.down_time))) AS duration

FROM events a 
JOIN events b 
ON  a.event < b.event 
    AND (a.event = 'e1' OR a.event = 'e2' OR a.event = 'e3' OR a.event = 'e4')
    AND (b.event = 'e1' OR b.event = 'e2' OR b.event = 'e3' OR b.event = 'e4') 
WHERE   ( a.down_time <= b.up_time )
AND     ( a.up_time >= b.down_time );

SELECT * FROM overlap1;
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| overlaps | downtime            | uptime              | duration |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| e1-e2    | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 |        1 |
| e1-e2    | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |        2 |
| e1-e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |        4 |
| e2-e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 |        2 |
| e2-e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |        3 |
| e1-e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 |        3 |
| e2-e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 |        2 |
| e2-e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 |        1 |
| e3-e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 |        5 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+

CREATE VIEW overlap2 AS
SELECT
CONCAT(a.overlaps,'-',b.overlaps) AS overlaps,
GREATEST(a.downtime,b.downtime) AS downtime,
LEAST(a.uptime,b.uptime) AS uptime,
TIMEDIFF( LEAST(a.uptime,b.uptime),
GREATEST(a.downtime,b.downtime) ) AS duration

FROM overlap1 a
JOIN overlap1 b 
ON a.overlaps < b.overlaps
AND (a.overlaps = 'e1-e2' OR a.overlaps = 'e3-e4')
AND (b.overlaps = 'e1-e2' OR b.overlaps = 'e3-e4')

WHERE   ( a.downtime <= b.uptime )
AND ( a.uptime >= b.downtime );

SELECT * FROM overlap2;
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| overlaps    | downtime            | uptime              | duration |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| e1-e2-e3-e4 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 00:00:01 |
| e1-e2-e3-e4 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 00:00:01 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I would like to achieve this with a single query if possible ..any help appreciated !

Comment: Luckily, time is linear. Consider two events, x and y. An overlap occurs when x_start < y_end AND x_end > y_start

Comment: thanks Strawberry ..i have a WHERE clause that should cover that ..i am trying to combine the two seperate queries into one at the moment but not quite there yet !

Comment: Isn't the desired result simply 1-10 (9 seconds)??

Comment: i want to identify when all the events happen together and how long this lasts ..this occurs twice in the above each with a duration of 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

Following query will meet your requirement:

```
select e1.* from events e1
join events e2 on e1.down_time>=e2.down_time and e1.up_time<=e2.up_time
group by e1.event
having count(*)=(select count(*) from events)
```

Verify the result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c733/4

Comment: sorry for late reply Seahawk ..many thanks for your response but this query does not appear to cover a case where say e2 occurs twice within overall time period which i may need. Have edited to reflect new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The following query fetches the minimum duration item and checks if other records fall in the span:

```
SELECT 
    1 Overlap,
    ev.down_time overlap_down_time,
    ev.up_time,
    SEC_TO_TIME(ev.secondsdiff) overlap_duration
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(ev1.id) matchcount, ev2.*
    FROM
        events ev1
    JOIN (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, down_time, up_time) secondsdiff, ev.*
    FROM
        events ev) minevent
    ORDER BY secondsdiff ASC
    LIMIT 1) ev2 ON (ev1.down_time <= ev2.down_time
        AND ev1.up_time >= ev2.up_time)) ev
WHERE
    ev.matchcount = (SELECT 
            COUNT(id)
        FROM
            events);
```

### Output

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| Overlap | overlap_down_time   | up_time             | overlap_duration |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|       1 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01         |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: sorry for late reply James ..many thanks for your response but this query does not appear to cover a case where say e2 occurs twice within overall time period which i may need. Have edited to reflect new requirement.